# Nexus 7 2012 with newer desktop Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-touch, tablet, nexus-7, arm

I read many about that and because I dont know what do with N7 I'd like install some linux on that. :-)

In last days and nights I trying that and I succesfull installed Ubuntu Touch Preview and [Ubuntu 13.04](http://webtrickz.com/guide-to-install-ubuntu-13-04-on-nexus-7-using-windows/), but I'd like install newer version which have support and active repositories or maybe older 12.04 which still have support.

Is there any change how I can do it? I found some tutorials how (maybe) install newer version, but only over Ubuntu desktop on PC and I must do it over Windows laptop. Or if someone have experience with other distro or some other OS.

Thanks for help and tips.

Answer (score 0):

I have also a Nexus 7 (2012), I followed the instructions at :
https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/

but to be able to flash the nexus with Ubuntu, I replaced the step involving ubuntu-device-flash by this command :

sudo ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel="ubuntu-touch/trusty" --device=grouper --bootstrap
I also tried a lot of things before this, one of them was in the recovery mode: I wiped the cache.

but, I'm not perfecty sure all that is good, as, even though I succesfully installed Ubuntu on the Nexus, I'm stuck at the unlock page : It doesn't accept the swipe from the right edge.

good luck !